# How do I create a launcher that updates my python game given a google drive url?

Tags: installation, launcher

Ideally i'd love to have

installing from the internet using hardcoded url,
creating shortcuts,
checking form web page available application versions,
showing older versions for rollback,
allowing different versions installed simultaneously,
allowing uninstallation.

I have the game as an exe with the exeption of the save data and I know how to make an installer for this exe that gives it a shortcut on the desktop

Is there a way to make such an installer and how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays many games do have some kind of a launcher.

I'd start with the following approach. We need URL:
- https://googledrive.com/version. Here you will store the latest version number and the difference in files which need to be updated and for previous updates. Like:

```
[{ 
  "version": "1.21.1",
  "files": [
              "path":"game_file_1.data", "checksum": '1289f81',
              "path":"game_file_2.data", "checksun": '321321'
            ]
},
{
  "version": "1.21.0",
  "files": [...],
 }
 ...]
```

1. Save version to one on the game files.
2. Save the url of the server. When the launcher starts send the request to this url and in the response give back the version number and files for each 'patch'
3. On the launcher side check whether the version number matches the one on the server. If it does not match download the file from the list. Before doing the actual download calculate checksum to make sure you won't download file twice if download process breaks.

Comment: I don't fully understand what programing language is that and what do you mean by save version on one of the game files?

Comment: This is not a particular programming language. The notation I mentioned is a simple JSON. Simpler: you create the file with array of objects. Each of the objects has following fields: version(version of your game) and files: (array of files which changed once you updated the version of your game). To save the version in one of the game files is to create the file like version.txt in the game folder and save there a number like '1.21'. After the game launches you need to check the local game version versus the game version on your server and retrieve the list of updates in the do not match.

Comment: how would I send a request for a server version as it is a google drive link